# String.equal() funtion not working with value from `R.string`

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio, equals

I want to compare my result(string) and I'm using following code to check it.

```
result = "password";
if (result.equals(R.string.myResponse)) {
     //do something
}
```

R.string file

```
<string name="myResponse">password</string>
```

Above function is not working and doesn't get into `if` part.
However, If I replace `R.string.myResponse` with its actual value by `if(result.equals("password"))` then it is working fine.

What's the problem using string value from `R.string`

Comment: Have you tried to use a Debugger?

Comment: try `if (result.equals(getString(R.string.myResponse)))`

Comment: `R.string.myResponse` will return and integer to you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

R.string.myResponse is not a string it is an `ID` for a string.

You need to get the string using that `ID`.

Something like `context.getString(R.string.myResponse)` or if you are in an activity or fragment then just `getString(R.string.myResponse)`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
  R.string.myResponse
```

with

```
 getResources().getString(R.string.myResponse);
```

Answer (score 0):

`R.string.myResponse` will return an integer value that is the ID of the particular string resource. You can use `getString(R.string.myResponse)` to get the String stored for that ID. To be on safe side use `getResources().getString(R.string.myResponse)` as `getString()` sometimes return null.